# Parameter variable in expression for Calculate Field Python Script?

Tags: arcpy, python-parser, field-calculator

Here is what I have

```
import arcpy

inputFC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (0)         #Feature Class  
inputField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (1)      #Field to manipulate  
inputChar = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (2)      #The character(s) I wish to replace  
replChar = arcpy.GetParameterAsText (3)        #The character(s) I wish to replace them with  

arcpy.CalculateField_management(inputFC, inputField, !inputField!.replace(inputChar, replChar), "PYTHON_9.3")
```

I am trying to use the "`CalculateField_management`" tool with a variable instead of a direct field for the 3rd input like I am with the first 2, but I can't seem to fit it in with the expression. I want it to take the value of the existing string and replace the characters I desire. How is the expression supposed to be written?

I have tried a variety of ways and can't figure it out.
For example: `!inputField!.replace, '"!inputField!'".replace, inputField.replace, '"inputField"'.replace`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track with `'"!inputField!'".replace`, just needed some variable substitution. Otherwise, you'd just be operating on the value contained by the variable, eg `"myField".replace('abc', 'def')` which doesn't have much meaning.

So, you need to create a string, which is easy with string formatting.

```py
inputField= 'myField'
inputChar = 'abc'
replChar = 'def'

expr = "!{field}!.replace('{old}', '{new}')".format(field=inputField,
                                                    old=inputChar,
                                                    new=replChar)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(inputFC, inputField, expr, "PYTHON_9.3")

>>> expr
"!myField!.replace('abc', 'def')" 
>>> print(expr)
!myField!.replace('abc', 'def')
```

Tricky to write, so I prefer cursors:

```py
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inputFC, inputField) as cursor:
     for row in cursor:
         new = row[0].replace(inputChar, replChar)
         cursor.updateRow([new])
```

Comment: The UpdateCursor works great. I tried fiddling around with it previously and couldn't figure it out so thanks a lot. :)